# Is it possible to store 0001 in int?

Tags: java

The product (25 years old product) I am working on is very large and complicated. So let me explain what I want in simple scenario:

I've declared an `int` variable. Say, `int var = 0001;`

When we try to retrieve the value of `var`, we'll get `1`.

Now, my requirement is, is it possible to return `0001`, without changing the signature or return type of the method?

Comment: Can you post a little more code?

Comment: no. `0001 == 1`

Comment: 25 years product suffering from 0001 vs 1 issue? Kill it with fire.

Comment: or yes, but the callee needs to know it should expect four numbers.

Comment: When you're assigning `0001`, this isn't actually "0001", but `1` in octal (in this case, same as `1` in decimal).

Comment: How do you know it's `1`? You printed it, right? So I guess you want to print `0001` when you get `1`. Try `System.out.printf("%04d%n", 1);`. Or `String.format("%04d", 1);`

Comment: if you need leading zeros then you will need to create a new method returning a formatted string

Comment: Be careful, numbers that start from 0 are considered to be octal (base 8), e.g. 010 == 8

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you know how much digits number have you can use

```
String.format("%04d", number);
```

int will allways return 1

Comment: @johnchen902 print number using at least 4 digits, adding leading "0" if needed.

Comment: Thanks much. Works perfectly for my scenario.

Comment: @LadislavDANKO: In Stack Over Flow, you can accept an answer only after 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot store `0001` as an `int`.

An `int` stores a *number*, i.e. `1`. You need a *format*.

When you "retrieve" your `int` you implicitly `Integer.toString()` it; this is the point at which you need to tell Java how to format it.

You haven't really given any information but I suppose you always need 4 digits, in this case the format mask `0000` ought to do the trick.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int i = 1;
    final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000");                
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(i));
}
```

Output:

```
0001
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not start numbers from 0 - in Java they considered to be *octal (base 8)* - 
unless you have strange outcomes, e.g.:

> 001 == 1
>
> 010 == 8  // Octal 10 == Decimal 8
>
> 0123 == 83 // Octal 123 is Decimal 83
>
> ```
> 08 - error! This's not an octal value
> ```

etc.

Instead use *formatting* whenever you want to print out your number

```
 int number = 1; // <- Just a decimal integer
 String result = String.form("My number is %04d in dddd format", number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. The value is actually octal and you need to take care of conversions etc. or
2. This is just a data presentation problem and you need to transform it into a string with required left padding before interacting with the system that's almost as old as I am.

Answer (score 0):

Before zero of an int treat as Octal in Java. So, You cannot store 0001 as an int.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact length of the number. For example 6.

```
int x = 5
String s = "";
s = ""+x;
while(s.length() < 6){
   s = "0"+s;
}
```

This will print 000005.

Answer (score -3):

After some lookout i found an working answer.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0000");
int i=1;
i=df.format(i);
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Can you please explain how you fit this in actual solution?